# Php post method gives errors when insert data in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am using post method in php using ajax and javascript when add then its gives erorr..in this project i am made class and model please help me how to resolve this probleme..

**Manufacturer.php**

```
class Manufacturer {
    private $table = 'manufacturer';

    public function select() {

    }
    public function selectAll(){
        $result = DB::select($this->table, ["id", "name"]);
        return $result;
    }

    public function insert($columns = []) {

        $result = DB::select($this->table, ["name"], "name = '$columns[name]'");

        if(count($result) > 0) {
            return "duplicate";
        }

        $result = DB::insert($this->table, $columns);
        if($result) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "failure";
        }
    }
}
```

In below i am showing js file which is use in this project...

**manufacturer.js**

```
function addManufacturere() {
    var manufacturer_name = $('#manufacturer_name').val().trim();
    if(manufacturer_name == '') {
        alert("Please input manufacturere name");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            'url':'services/add_manufacturer.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: {'name' : manufacturer_name},
            success: function(data) {
                switch(data) {

                    case 'success':
                            var msg = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">';
                                msg += '<strong>Success!</strong> Manufacturer entry added successfully.';
                                msg += '</div>';
                            break;
                    case 'error':
                            var msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">';
                                msg += '<strong>Failed!</strong> Something went wrong, Please try again later.';
                                msg += '</div>';
                            break;
                    case 'duplicate':
                            var msg = '<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">';
                                msg += '<strong>Warning!</strong> Entry already exist.';
                                msg += '</div>';
                            break;
                }
                $('#alerts').html(msg);
                $("#alerts").show();
                $("#alerts").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my add_manufacturer.php is the my services which is made for insert the value of manufacturer when adding then its gives error failure which is checking in classes.Please help me how to resolve the error.

**add_manufacturer.php**

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$manufacturer = new Manufacturer();

echo $manufacturer->insert(["name"=>$_REQUEST["name"]]);
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: its return failure..

Comment: in Manufacturer.php i am checking $result then its alwayas returns failure..@JayBlanchard

Comment: That is not an error, that is your message when it doesn't work. What is the actual error?

Comment: its always return message return "failure";

Comment: That is ***your*** message, the one you say to give out. There should be an error in the error logs.

Comment: why my data is not insert into database..please help me..sir

Comment: I cannot tell you that until you tell us what the actual error is.

Comment: in network only return failure

Comment: No it doesn't. There is an error log for your website and it will show you exactly what the errors are unless you've setup PHP to suppress errors or not report them.

Comment: actual arror is it return  if($result) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "failure";
        }

Comment: That is not the actual error, that is just your code.

Comment: its return on my message failure and data is not insert

Comment: OK - it is obvious that what I am saying is not clear to you. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You can do three things to troubleshoot this 1. When you go to developer tools and click on network tab you can able to see the post request been initiated to the server method (add_manufacturer.php) 2. You can log the value been posted as Jay mentioned to see whether you can able to receive the value been posted. 3. Try to insert a record into the table giving value only for name column to see whether you can able to insert it as it could be an issue caused because of passing null value to other columns (id) Hope it helps

Comment: Please check my code resolve issue ...why data is not insert into database..

Comment: in network tab it show failure....

Comment: In header its return name: tata but it is not insert into database....

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcis-master\services\add_manufacturer.php on line 7
failure

Comment: its gives error Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcis-master\services\add_manufacturer.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

To use $_REQUEST variable you have to have a form in html or virtual formData() that has the method equal to GET and POST. You are using json format data structure which is not accessible by $_REQUEST[]. You can do the job by modifying the manufacturer.js as-

```
function addManufacturere() {
var manufacturer_name = $('#manufacturer_name').val().trim();
if (manufacturer_name == '') {
    alert("Please input manufacturere name");
} else {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('name', manufacturer_name);
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'services/add_manufacturer.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "POST",
        data: form,
        success: function (data) {
            switch (data) {

                case 'success':
                    var msg = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">';
                    msg += '<strong>Success!</strong> Manufacturer entry added successfully.';
                    msg += '</div>';
                    break;
                case 'error':
                    var msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">';
                    msg += '<strong>Failed!</strong> Something went wrong, Please try again later.';
                    msg += '</div>';
                    break;
                case 'duplicate':
                    var msg = '<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">';
                    msg += '<strong>Warning!</strong> Entry already exist.';
                    msg += '</div>';
                    break;
            }
            $('#alerts').html(msg);
            $("#alerts").show();
            $("#alerts").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

}